# restful routes rename :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this routes

```
resources :posts, :controller => 'frontend/posts' do
 resources :photos, :controller => 'frontend/posts'
end
```

So `frontend/posts_controller` handles these requests:

```
/posts/:post_id/photos/:id
/posts/:id
```

Somtimes the `:id` means the photo id and in some cases the post id.
I want that post always uses `:post_id` . Is it possible to rename `:id` in `:post_id` without adding custom(`match` ...) routes?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just write your finders to handle both cases. It's easier than messing around with parameter names:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id] || params[:id])
```

That being said, I agree that it's annoying that the `:id` parameter changes names depending on the depth of the resource call.

Comment: Thanks.
I always did it this way but it's a pity that it's not possible to change the `:id` param.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of :post_id is what will differentiate between the two routes. Personally, unless I have a compelling reason to depart from convention, I try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or just goes further down the rabbit hole but can't you force it to be like that with:

```
match "posts/:post_id" => "posts#show"
```